# Is it idiomatic to use new type wrappers in Go for IDs?

Tags: go, idioms, newtype

In other statically-typed languages like Haskell, Scala, or Rust, sometimes for things like identifiers, one would wrap them in special types to help the compiler catch errors (e.g. preventing you from passing in another in-scope `String`) and to improve readability of the code by encoding responsibility at the type-level.

Some examples:

```hs
newtype UserId = UserId Integer
```

or

```scala
case class UserId(value: Long) extends AnyVal
```

or

```rust
struct UserId(u64);
```

All of these offer (usually) no runtime costs and little added clutter for improved peace of mind and dev-time documentation at the type level.

Go also has this ability:

```golang
type UserId uint64
```

My question is not whether or not this is possible, but whether this is something that is widespread and/or considered idiomatic or not in Go, and why.

Comment: This sort of thing is often done to create enum-like types (i.e., by declaring the type and defining constants of that type) and/or so that methods can be defined on the type.

Comment: > so that methods can be defined on the type

Yeah, this is also a valid reason for doing this in the other languages I mentioned, esp. the ones where overriding implementations (esp. on types you don't own) is not a thing :)

Comment: This is not at all unusual. For example: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration

Answer (score 1):

Go supports [type inference](https://tour.golang.org/basics/14) on compiler level. There is no runtime cost in the compiled binary.

With this type definition

```golang
type UserID uint64
```

Both of the following should result in the same binary:

```golang
uid := UserID(1)
```

```golang
var uid UserID = 1
```

And to my experience, development environment can understand both equally well. And they are both humanly-readable. I think I see more of the first one in production code than the second one.

As @AndySchweig mentioned in comment, this is usually used when the variable is a Enum like value.

```
type UserType uint

const (
  TypeVisitor UserType = 1
  TypeNormal = 2
  TypeAdmin = 3
)
```

or

```
type UserType uint

const (
  TypeVisitor UserType = iota
  TypeNormal
  TypeAdmin
)
```

The exported const would make code much more readable:

```golang
switch userType {
  case mylib.TypeVisitor:
    // do something
  case mylib.TypeNormal:
    // do something
  case mylib.TypeAdmin:
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Assuming I have a `type X uint` and a `type Y uint`, does the type system prevent me from e.g. adding an `X` and a `Y`? In other statically typed languages this is an important safety feature of "newtypes".

Comment: That's right. You cannot add variables of type X to type Y unless you do proper [type casting](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) explicitly.